# Circuit breakers in "ordinary" boxes

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker

In some buildings, I've noticed circuit breakers in what appear to be ordinary electrical boxes.  For example, in some musical practice rooms, the light, fan, and a receptacle are all switched by a breaker which is mounted in a way similar to a light switch, except for a placard explaining how to reset the breaker if it trips.  I would expect things were done this way so that someone who accidentally overloads the breaker would be able to reset it without having to find a custodian with a key to the main electrical box.

While I doubt that I'm going to rewire my kitchen any time soon, it is sometimes a nuisance having to go to the basement to reset a kitchen breaker if two high-draw appliances get used simultaneously on the wrong receptacles.  It would seem nicer as a design to have a master 40A feed to the kitchen and then have a 20A breaker near each receptacle so that any combination of receptacles could be used to draw up to 40A total, rather than to have to worry about which receptacles could be used together and then have to visit the basement in case of a mistake.  Would such a design satisfy code requirements (I would think having enough outlets total, driven through enough 20A breakers, and fed with at least 40A of capacity, should qualify)?  Would there be any problems with such a design?

Alternatively, are there any outlet assemblies with built-in breakers that would be approved for permanent installation (unlike e.g. power strips), and which could be safely fed from a greater-than-20A circuit?

Comment: What part of the world is this in?

Comment: Is there any labeling on these sorts of boxes you can find?

Comment: It's been a few years since I've seen one.  I think they were labeled with a manufacturer name (though I've completely forgotten what that would have been) and the aforementioned placard.  When I first saw one of those assemblies, I was confused by the purpose of the reset instructions since I didn't realize it was a circuit breaker--it just seemed like a switch with a stubby handle.  I remember where I first saw such things about 40 years ago, and have seen them occasionally since though I don't recall the specifics.

Comment: As Tyson asked it may help to know where in the world do you live and a photo of the box may also help.

Comment: @EdBeal: USA.  The ones I saw 40 years ago were in a Wisconsin elementary school that was built in the 1960s or 1970s.  I don't have a photo, nor do I remember the particular places I've seen these things since.

Comment: According to my dad, it was likely a pre-manufactured modular building.  His first question was “is it a ship or aircraft carrier?”  I then read the comments and told him it might have been a school in Wisconsin and he immediately had the comment, “I bet it’s a temporary or modular pre-fab building”.

Comment: @Tyson: It was a brick building.  The building had an older portion and a newer one, and I think the practice rooms were in the older one, across from the multi-purpose room.

Comment: My dad also adds (actually I’ve gotten quite an education on many related topics from asking him this question ) that in schools in those days the gym almost always used the breakers in the breaker panel as switching devices for the lights, that would have looked like a breaker box tho, and had a door.

Comment: this can be a self-help solution.  Receptacles and covers come in a variety of colors, and there are plastic labels too.

Comment: I have worked in older schools that all the wiring was green even the hot conductors so this can be tricky because government buildings in my current state the government buildings wiring like schools and forestry buildings don't require a licence and Oregon has some really lax rules for those installers requirements but some county's have over the top requirements for residential many of those were finally relaxed in the 2017 code to match the NEC. But government installation still in some cases the employee of the state can do work that a license is required for any other structure.

Comment: @EdBeal: I think what I saw was probably equivalent to what ThreePhaseEd describes as a spa panel or enclosed breaker, and from a practical perspective it would be a sensible way of doing things.  Not that I have any idea why a music practice room would have anything in it that would be likely to make accidental overloading a problem, but for some other scenarios having localized breakers could make sense.

Answer (score 1):

### What you may be seeing is a flush-mount version of a spa panel or enclosed breaker

From your description, I would reckon that what you are looking at is something akin to a "spa panel" disconnect or circuit breaker enclosure, only in a flush-mounted configuration (vs. the surface mounting typically attributed to spa panels and enclosed breakers).  These are usually 2-4 space loadcenters, with 70A to 125A bussing; larger versions use a breaker with line and load lugs instead, bolted to the box, and are called *enclosed circuit breakers*.

Comment: That sounds like that might be it.

Answer (score 0):

Modern kitchen electrical design is to have at least two separate 20 A circuits so that the high draw appliances are never used simultaneously on the same circuit. Over-current tripping of a breaker due to intentional overloading is unacceptable.

What you are describing is unnecessary, would be more expensive, and could have unforeseen faults and deficiencies. In the UK a high current (30 A or 40 A at 240 V) "ring circuit" is allowed with spurs off the ring to receptacles. A plug-in appliance will have a fuse in its plug (2 A, 5 A, 7 A, . . . ) to limit current to what the appliance wiring can take. The ring and spur reportedly uses marginally less copper wire. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_circuit

Comment: Electrically, it would be essentially equivalent to having a sub-panel in the kitchen, with a 20A breaker for each receptacle.  The difference would be that rather than having all the breakers in one panel, having them nearer the outlets might make things clearer.  If a kitchen design was intended to have a microwave plugged into one particular location, I suppose using a separate home-run for the microwave's receptacle might be another way of fixing problems with trying to use a toaster or blender at the same time as a microwave.  I was also inspired by the question about what to do with...

Comment: ...a 50A circuit that was left over after switching an electric stove to gas.  Using the wiring with a 20A breaker feeding normal outlets would work, but wiring sized for 50A should be able to feed more than one 20A circuit, if protection devices were installed between the 50A circuit and individual outlets.